# how to use a function to calculate the distance between two cities

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to write a function to calculate the distance between two cities.

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy import distance
capitals = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/j-rossi-nl/teaching-    data/main/2022_ITP/concap.csv')
capitals.head(5)
capitals.set_index('CapitalName', inplace = True)
capitals.loc["Amsterdam"]
def cities_distance(city_from: str, city_to: str = 'Amsterdam', cities: pd.DataFrame = capitals)->float:
```

I don't know how to select the capitallatitude and longitude when using geopy to calculate the distance. It needs to return the distance in kilometers.

Comment: there is no code is the function. did you mean to add something ?!?

Comment: But what have you tried ?  where are you stuck ? . . . the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As i mentioned i the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75114943/how-to-use-a-function-to-calculate-the-distance-between-two-cities/75115395#75115395) you need to specify target locations as `x, y` points as use @timeless in `cities_distance` function, particulary i do not think you take each latitude and longitude in a certain order then i use first two capitals.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use [`geopy.distance.geodesic`](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.distance.geodesic). Below, a proposition based on your code :

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.distance import geodesic

capitals = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/j-rossi-nl/teaching-data/main/2022_ITP/concap.csv",
                       index_col="CapitalName")

def cities_distance(city_from: str, city_to: str = "Amsterdam", cities: pd.DataFrame = capitals)->float:
    lat_long = ["CapitalLatitude", "CapitalLongitude"]

    origin = capitals.loc[city_from, lat_long].agg(tuple)
    destination = capitals.loc[city_to, lat_long].agg(tuple)

    return round(geodesic(origin,destination).km,2)
```

We use here [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`pandas.Series.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html) to form a tuple with the coordinatees of the origin capital and pass it as a keyword argument to `geodesic` :

> Parameters
> **point** : (`geopy.point.Point`), list or tuple of (latitude, longitude), or
> string as "%(latitude)s, %(longitude)s".) – Starting point.

NB : The [Geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) distance will give a measure of the shortest path between the two capitals.

Output :

```
cities_distance("Hargeisa")
#5912.67
```

Comment: hi,thanks first. But when I use this test system to run it, it says Tried cities_distance(city_from=Tokyo, city_to=Berlin), expected 8942.063215005555, but got 8942.06. BUT I delete the round function to 2 decimals, why is this problem happen?

Comment: I only use return geodesic(origin,destination).km. IS IT CORRECT?

Comment: You’re welcome. Yes, it is correct.

Comment: the code system says: Check the code for cities_distance, check that it is using the argument 'cities' and never the dataframe 'capitals'. why is this happen?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand. What do you mean by _code system_ ?

Comment: oh, it's our school's own system to check whether the ocde is correct.

Comment: Have the code system checked your code ?

Comment: yes, the result says Check the code for cities_distance, check that it is using the argument 'cities' and never the dataframe 'capitals'. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

In conjuntion with [`shapely.Geometry`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/geometry.html) and [`pyproj.Geod`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/geod.html)

> `geometry_length` Returns the geodesic length (meters) of the shapely geometry

```py
from pyproj import Geod
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
import pandas as pd
capitals = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/j-rossi-nl/teaching-data/main/2022_ITP/concap.csv",
                       index_col="CapitalName")

line_string = LineString([Point(capitals['CapitalLongitude'].iloc[0], capitals['CapitalLatitude'].iloc[0]), Point(capitals['CapitalLongitude'].iloc[1], capitals['CapitalLatitude'].iloc[1])])
geod = Geod(ellps="WGS84")

print(f"{geod.geometry_length(line_string):.3f}")
#10255732.456

print(f"{geod.geometry_length(line_string)/1000:.3f}") # k/m
#10255.732
```